# How to put local branch to origin with GitKraken?

Tags: branch, gitkraken

[image]

I created branches and it shows branch does not exist on origin when I pull files.

How to add my local branches to origin with GitKraken?

No cmd and GitHub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Right click on the local branch and from the context menu select Set
  Upstream
  [image]
- Then type a name for your remote branch and click ok.

Ref: https://reganmusic.wordpress.com/2016/07/19/branching-in-gitkraken/

Comment: Or you just click `Push`. GitKraken will then ask what your remote branch should be named, create it and push.